# How to unlock Mutex twice

Tags: go

Is it safe to unlock a mutex twice?
My code:

```
var m sync.RWMutex = sync.RWMutex{}

func Read() {
    m.RLock()
    defer m.RUnlock()

    // Do something that needs lock
    err := SomeFunction1()
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    m.RUnlock()

    // Do something that does not need lock
    SomeFunction2()

}
```

I need `defer m.RUnlock()` for the case `SomeFunction1()` returns error. But when `SomeFunction1()` returns without error, `m` will be unlocked twice by `m.RUnlock()` and `defer m.RUnlock()`.

Is it safe to unlock the mutex twice? If not, how should I fix my code?

Comment: Note that when you find yourself wanting to do this (lock and unlock a mutex at various weird points in a function), it's *usually* a sign that your code is not really properly structured. There are some oddball cases where this is appropriate, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it safe for unlocking a mutex twice?

Nope, you shouldn't unlock the mutex twice. It's a **run-time error** according to [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#RWMutex.RUnlock).

> RUnlock undoes a single RLock call; it does not affect other simultaneous readers. It is a run-time error if rw is not locked for reading on entry to RUnlock.

---

> If not, how should I fix my code?

I would recommend to keep the `defer` but only `m.RUnlock()` in case of error. This can easily scale in case you add more function calls between `SomeFunction1()` and `SomeFunction2()`.

```
func Read() {
    var err error
    m.RLock()
    defer func() {
        if err != nil {
            m.RUnlock()
        }
    }()
    

    // Do something that needs lock
    err = SomeFunction1()
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    m.RUnlock()

    // Do something that does not need lock
    SomeFunction2()
}
```

Try it on [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/e16AHOm6S2O)!

Answer (score 0):

Unlocking an unlocked Mutex will cause a panic.

You can simply remove the `defer` and add it in the if condition:

```
var m sync.RWMutex = sync.RWMutex{}

func Read() {
    m.RLock()

    // Do something that needs lock
    err := SomeFunction1()
    if (err != nil) {
        m.RUnlock()
        return
    }

    m.RUnlock()

    // Do something that does not need lock
    SomeFunction2()
}
```

Or even better (with a minor impact on readability):

```
func Read() {
    m.RLock()

    err := SomeFunction1()
    m.RUnlock()
    if (err != nil) {
        return
    }

    SomeFunction2()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From godoc:

> It is a run-time error if m is not locked on entry to Unlock.

So, don't do that.

Easiest fix is to not use defer unlock, but unlock it at every possible exit. Or, you can also do this, but it is not easy to read:

```
func Read() {
    if err := func() {
      m.RLock()
      defer m.RUnlock()

      // Do something that needs lock
      err := SomeFunction1()
      if err != nil {
          return err
      }(); err != nil {
        return err
     }

    // Do something that does not need lock
    SomeFunction2()

}
```